# Scala internal DSL constraints

Tags: scala, dsl

Let

```
case class Box(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)    
case class Boxes(s: Set[Box])
```

and

```
val m = Boxes(Set(Box(1,2,3), Box(2,3,4), Box(3,4,5)))
```

The DSL below allows for specifying constraints on the fields of `Box` collected over `Boxes`, for instance,

```
m x (>,1)
res: Boxes = Boxes(Set(Box(2,3,4), Box(3,4,5)))

m y (>=,4)
res: Boxes = Boxes(Set(Box(3,4,5)))
```

The DSL,

```
abstract class Ord
case object >= extends Ord
case object > extends Ord

case class Constraints(xs: Boxes) {
  def x(o: Ord, i: Int) = o match {
    case >= => Boxes( xs.s.filter(_.x >= i) )
    case >  => Boxes( xs.s.filter(_.x >  i) )
  }
  def y(o: Ord, j: Int) = o match {
    case >= => Boxes( xs.s.filter(_.y >= j) )
    case >  => Boxes( xs.s.filter(_.y >  j) )
  }
}

implicit def b2c(m: Boxes) = Constraints(m)
```

The enquiries,

- can `Constraints` be made more scalable for additional `Ord` and/or `Box` dimensions ?
- can the following syntax be implemented

  m x > 1

Comment: I think `m x > 1` can be implemented, but there might be problems with the associativity/precedence (in case you might want to support things like: `m 1 < x < 4`).

Comment: Many Thanks, note changed from `Seq` to `Set` so it may ease up `(m x > 1) intersect (m x < 4)`